# Why bootstrap carousel is not working properly and how can i solve this?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a full-width image slider with bootstrap but images are not sliding .just the first image is showing.here is the codepen link:
https://codepen.io/Razu381/pen/XQJVzg

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="height: 100vh;">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/wsanter" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/wsanter" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/wsanter" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `jQuery library.` before all `script`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```